# Why does this command kill my shell?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

**Update:** This is a more general command that is more reproducible. ShellFish identified that there is a more general pattern:

```
non-existingcommand & existingcommand &
```

for example,

```
xyz & echo &
```

Also, I had a coworker try over an ssh connection and his connection was closed after running the command. So this doesn't appear to be limited to a certain terminal emulator.

**Original question**:

```
echo?a=1&b=2|3&c=4=
```

Behavior:

After executing the command, my current Gnome Terminal tab closes without warning.

Background:

We were testing a URL with a curl command but forgot to quote it or escape the special characters (hence the ampersands and equals signs). Expecting some nonsense about syntax issues or commands not found, we instead watched our shell simply quit. We spent some time narrowing the command down to the minimum that would cause the behavior.

We are using Gnome Terminal on Ubuntu 14.10. Strangely, the behavior is not present on another box I have running byobu even if I detach from the session. It also doesn't happen on Cygwin. Unfortunately I'm limited to testing with Ubuntu 14.10 otherwise.

Note: The following command also kills my terminal but *only about half of the time*:

```
echo?a=1&b=2&c=3=
```

Additional tests:

Someone recommend using a subshell...

```
guest-cvow8T@chortles:~$ bash -c 'echo?a=1&b=2|4&c=3='
bash: echo?a=1: command not found
guest-cvow8T@chortles:~$ bash: 4: command not found
```

No exit.

Comment: If you run that in a sub-shell (i.e. `bash -c 'echo?a=1&b=2|3&c=4='`) does it exit? Does it print any messages when it exits? What shell are you using in gnome-terminal (What does `echo $SHELL` output?)? What does `set +o | grep errexit` output?

Comment: It does not exit when running it with `bash -x`, if it's stored in a script that is. This is awesomely strange behavior!

Comment: Is there any mention in the system log about a crash?

Comment: Note that `echo?a=1&b=2|3&` also kills the terminal, which is shorter than the first one.

Comment: @Close voter, this is not about the shell *per se*, but about analyzing a potential parser failure (or worse). As such, I believe the questioner will get better answers here than on Super User.

Comment: The general behavior is this: `non-existing command & any command &`. A command consisting of this structure always kills the terminal.

Comment: It's definitely a [tag:bash] issue, the same thing does not happen using [tag:sh].

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue. Please post your bash version and the version of gnome-terminal

Comment: @hek2mgl I can using `GNOME Terminal 3.6.2` and `GNU bash, version 4.3.11(1)-release (i686-pc-linux-gnu)`.

Comment: @ShellFish I could reproduce it using `123 & ls &`  - I cannot reproduce the example in the question. Probably we should change the question?

Comment: @hek2mgl Yes, now that a more general pattern has been found the question should indeed be changed.

Comment: I've moved the most reproducible example to the top of the question.

Comment: Not reproducible on debian with bash `4.2+dfsg-0.1+deb7`. Tried all mentioned versions.

Comment: Reproducible on `gnome-terminal`, `xfce-terminal`, `xterm` on `Xubuntu 14.04.1 LTS`, `GNU Bash 4.3.11`

Comment: I had a coworker try while he was ssh'd and it actually closed his ssh connection. So this doesn't appear to simply be a terminal emulator issue. I will update the OP with this info.

Comment: doesn't happen in `GNU bash, version 3.2.25(1)-release (i686-redhat-linux-gnu)`

Comment: The existing command part of that pattern is necessary for this to fail? A non-existent command (run in the background) by itself is not enough?

Comment: If you run `trap 'echo SIGNALLED >> /tmp/shell.log' INT` and then trigger this behavior does the trap handler trigger?

Comment: In a quick test on 14.04 `INT` does not trigger. I also can't reproduce the exit reliably. I saw it a few times early on but haven't seen it in a bunch of recent tests.

Comment: Ubuntu GNOME 15.04 with `command-not-found` installed, I can't reproduce behavior. https://gist.github.com/cprn/deb6d00fd01ded3b4237#file-crash

Comment: @CyprianGuerra Did you try it repeatedly? I couldn't get it to reliably happen either but I did see it if I hammered on it hard enough (get a set of test scripts set up and run them in a tight loop and you'll probably see if assuming the problem still exists). I was beginning to think it was a race and/or stack smash problem of some sort.

Comment: @EtanReisner You're more or less right. [Test](https://gist.github.com/cprn/46c8ccf1bfb107b4dcd1#file-crash) in a loop: 5, 10, even 200 iterations works fine but when I put it in a loop of 500+ iterations it crashes circa one out of three times. I'm not convinced it proves anything, though. It's running 1000k+ processes almost at once.

Comment: @CyprianGuerra Add `set -x` to your tests so you see the commands that are being run and you'll see an `exit` happening when it "crashes" and no indication that anything is actually crashing or breaking in some other, more stressed/killed/etc. sort of way.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I could reproduce this issue in an Ubuntu VM but not on an OEL VM. Difference was, on Ubuntu the package `command-not-found` was installed, and it provides the python script `/usr/lib/command-not-found`. This script is responsible for exiting the shell.

In `/etc/bash.bashrc`, there is a function `command-not-found_handle` , which executes `/usr/lib/command-not-found`. Hence, the terminal exits when we try to execute such commands. When I commented out the call to `/usr/lib/command-not-found`, the issue was no longer reproducible.

From my `/etc/bash.bashrc`:

```
function command_not_found_handle {
     #check because c-n-f could've been removed in meantime 
     if [ -x /usr/lib/command-not-found ]; then 
          /usr/bin/python /usr/lib/command-not-found -- "$1"
          return $?
     elif [ -x /usr/share/command-not-founf/command-not-found ]; then
          /usr/bin/python /usr/share/command-not-founf/command-not-found -- "$1"
          return $?
     else
          printf "%s:command not found\n" "$1"
          return 127
     fi
}
```

Comment: Wow, great find! Any idea why the script causes the shell to quit occasionally?

Comment: Is that snippet **exactly** the content of that function in the `/etc/bash.bashrc` file? Because that's poorly indented and syntactically invalid.

Comment: That snippet is from /etc/bash.bashrc script but I have typed it instead of copying.

Comment: Please copy and paste or be extra careful to transcribe it correctly because this is virtually certain to have been transcribed incorrectly. A quick look at the utopic package on packages.ubuntu.com shows a function that is effectively identical to this barring the erroneous `]` after `then`.

Comment: I can't see any reason for that to cause the controlling shell to exit. The only thing I could see would be a signalled/interrupted `command-not-found` binary cascading upwards.

Comment: The command-not-found handler in Bash is not necessarily robust in the have of errors. I have seen fairly drastic results in the past when it ran code with errors or was knterupted.

Comment: Arguably `bash` should be fixed, then. The weak link in a plugin chain should not be the host itself.